# How should I refer to 'people' that propose a proposal?

Tags: single-word-requests

I received a `proposal` for a project.

When addressing the authors of said `proposal`, how should I refer to them?

Should I say:

`As argued by the proponents ...`

I don't want to use the word `authors`, since it may not be appropriate as they may not be the original authors of said proposal.

Edit: Forgot to add that this takes place in a formal scenario.

Comment: I think you're correct that "proponents" would be the right word.  From Merriam-Webster: *Did You Know?  Proponent comes from the same Latin word as propose, so a proponent is someone who proposes something...*   // "Proposer" is also a word, but it might sound awkward in a formal setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are actually in support of a project or some theory or other proposal that you mentioned then you could use:

proponents

[supporters](https://www.google.com/search?q=supporter%20definition&oq=supporter%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5244j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

> a person who approves of and encourages someone or something (typically a public figure, a movement or party, or a policy).

If they are not necessarily in favor of it but they are submitting requests for feedback, comments, or bids:

[petitioners](https://www.google.com/search?q=petition%20definition&oq=petition&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i67k1l2j0i20k1j0l7.106438.107459.0.108366.8.8.0.0.0.0.136.812.0j7.7.0....0...1.1.64.serp..1.7.811...35i39k1j0i131k1.Umxv7xlbyIg)

> a formal written request, typically one signed by many people, appealing to authority with respect to a particular cause.

[requesters](http://www.yourdictionary.com/requester)

> Requester is defined as the person who asks for something or who makes a request.

You could use [clients](https://www.google.com/search?q=client%20definition&oq=client%20de&aqs=chrome.0.0l3j69i57j0l2.4078j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) in pretty much either case.

Answer (score 2):

If your formal process began with a "Request for Proposal", "Supply Requirement", "Invitation to Bid" or similarly titled document, it should contain the term that you are looking for.

Depending on the nature of the work, you might consider **potential vendor**, **potential contractor**, **project candidate** or the like.  However, if it's a formal process in which others have participated, it would be best to follow the precedents already set by your organization.

Comment: I like **candidate** and would also suggest ***applicant***.